# R regexpr replace text between brackets with respective inputs from a character vector (create mad lib)

Tags: r, regex

I might have a couple character vectors:

```
cv <- "[dramatically/immensely] [increases/improves] [one's/your] career prospects in the field and allows [one/you] to pursue positions in"
```

or

```
cv <- "While [holders of/students with/graduates with] a degree in"
```

I want to take the word choices in brackets, and choose one of the options.  For example, between `"[dramatically/immensely]"`, I want my code to choose (randomly), either `"dramatically"` or `"immensely"`.  Or between `[holders of/students with/graduates with]` I want my code to choose either `holders of`, `students with`, or `graduates with`.  I also need to make sure it makes sense, so if the first choice from something like `"[your/one's]"` will dictate that the second

So far, I have:

```
library(foreach)

wordChoices <- gsub("(\\[|\\])", "",regmatches(phrase1,gregexpr("\\[.*?\\]",phrase1))[[1]])
randomWords <- unlist(foreach(wordChoice=wordChoices) %do% {
        sample(strsplit(wordChoice,"/")[[1]],1)
      })
      if (any(regexpr("(you)",randomWords)>0)) {
        randomWords <- unlist(foreach(randomWord=randomWords) %do% {
        randomWord <- gsub("\\bone's\\b","your",randomWord)
        randomWord <- gsub("\\bone\\b","you",randomWord)
        })
      }
```

I end up with:

```
print(randomWords)
[1] "immensely" "increases" "your"      "you"
```

Now I am hoping to substitute these in for the respective spots in the sentence, but I'm stuck.

I hope to have this:

```
cv <- "immensely increases your career prospects in the field and allows you to pursue positions in"
```

EDIT:  I think I have an idea for a solution.  Loop through each replacement word and do a non-greedy replace of choices in brackets.  Each time, you'll replace a choice, so the next choice will be the first match on the next loop.

Comment: Can u show the expected output

Comment: I edited my question. Thanks!

Comment: Are u saying that for each instance of `[]`, the elements selected should be random?

Comment: yes, just using sample(x,1).  I think I found a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we need to choose randomly one of the words within the `[]`, we could try `gsubfn`

```
library(gsubfn)
f1 <- function(string){
   gsubfn("(\\[[^]]*\\])", ~sapply(strsplit(x,
      "[][/]"), function(y) sample(y[y!=""])[1]), string)
 }

f1(cv)
#[1] "dramatically increases one's career prospects in the field and allows one to pursue positions in"

f1(cv)
#[1] "immensely improves one's career prospects in the field and allows you to pursue positions in"

cv1 <- "While [holders of/students with/graduates with] a degree in"
f1(cv1)
#[1] "While holders of a degree in"
f1(cv1)
#[1] "While students with a degree in"
```